# Where can I download VS2010 professional? (or can't I?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This seems like a weird problem. I've just upgraded to a brand new PC and I can't for the life of me work out where I can get visual studios 2010 from. I have my product key ready to go.

Has MS discontinued this product? If so is there a work around? Is my only option to (dare I say it) upgrade.

Comment: VS 2017 is out now.  A lot of the features in 2010 pro are now in community version of recent VS releases.  If you use 2010, you'll miss out on things like NuGet.  I can't say I'd recommend that.

Comment: Old VS versions are available through an MSDN subscription.

Comment: In my opinion, parts of the UI for VS 2010 were the pinnacle.  Much of the UI has gone downhill since that version.  I use 2022 now, but I still have 2010 for checking in changes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=download+visual+studio+2010) there's no more *Visual Studio 2010* for download from their (official) site.

Personally I really recommend you go straight to [2017 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15) - it has **everything** the *2010 Professional* has and **more**.

The "more" includes built-in support for [GitHub](https://github.com/), "almost" full support for C++11 and some support for C++14, Windows 10 SDK, parallel builds, built-in support for [**Linux remote build/debugging**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIiFuBczd6A)... The list goes on and on.

Comment: Does it have the wonderful VS 2010 Source Control Explorer / TFS interface?

Comment: There's a built-in Source Control Explorer and a TFS as well. For everything else - there's an extension for you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-11508 . I'm talking about MSVC 2022, of course (because WHY would you still be on the old one?)

Comment: I do development in 2022.  But I use 2010 for checking in because I find the UI for that to be vastly superior.

Answer (score 1):

You can get old versions of VS here:
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads

As long as you have a license for it, you should be able to download it. Especially old versions are only downloadable as ISO files, so you may want a tool to mount them, like this:
https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/